# How do I copy the weights of a Keras network in to a Theano network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, theano

I have a deep network implemented and trained in Keras. How can I grab all the weights in this network and copy them to the weights in a similar network implemented in pure Theano?
As an example, suppose I want to copy the learned weights of the following simple net in Keras:

```
#### construct the model 
CNN_model = Sequential()
CNN_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,224,224)))
CNN_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))   
CNN_model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
CNN_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))   
CNN_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
CNN_model.add(Flatten())
CNN_model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))       
CNN_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

to the weights (`Wb_params`) of the same network implemented in Theano:

```
#########################################################
layer0 = ConvLayer(input, filter_shape0)
layer1 = ConvLayer(layer0.output, filter_shape1)
layer2 = PoolLayer(layer1.output)
layer3 = FCLayer(layer2.output.flatten(2), 4096)
layer4 = DropoutLayer(layer3.output)
Wb_params = layer3.params + layer1.params + layer0.params
#########################################################
class ConvLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, inp, filter_shape, activation=RELU):
        input_shape = T.shape(inp)     
        assert input_shape[1] == filter_shape[1]
        fan_in = np.prod(filter_shape)
        fan_out = np.prod(filter_shape[0], filter_shape[2:])
        w_bound = np.sqrt(6. / (fan_in + fan_out))
        w_values = np.asarray(RNG.uniform(low=-w_bound, high=+w_bound, size=filter_shape), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        self.w = theano.shared(value=w_values, borrow=True)
        b_values = np.zeros(filter_shape[0], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        self.b = theano.shared(value=b_values, borrow=True)
        conv_out = conv2d(input=inp, filters=self.w, filter_shape=filter_shape, input_shape=input_shape)
        self.out = activation(conv_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]

class PoolLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, inp, pool_size=(2, 2)):
        self.out = pool.pool_2d(input=inp, ds=pool_size, ignore_border=True)
        self.params = None

class FCLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, inp, num_hidden, activation=RELU):  
        fan_in = T.shape(inp)[0]
        fan_out = num_hidden
        w_bound = np.sqrt(6. / (fan_in + fan_out))
        w_values = np.asarray(RNG.uniform(low=-w_bound, high=+w_bound, size=(fan_in, fan_out)), dtype=theano.config.floatX)
        self.w = theano.shared(value=w_values, borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(value=np.zeros(fan_out, dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)

        fc_out = T.dot(inp, self.w) + self.b
        self.out = activation(fc_out)
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]

class DropoutLayer(object):
    seed_common = np.random.RandomState(0) 
    layers = []
    def __init__(self, inp, prob_drop=0.5):
        self.prob_drop = prob_drop
        self.prob_keep = 1.0 - prob_drop
        self.flag_on = theano.shared(np.cast[theano.config.floatX](1.0))
        self.flag_off = 1.0 - self.flag_on
        seed_this = DropoutLayer.seed_common.randint(0, 2**31-1)
        mask_rng = RandomStreams(seed_this)
        self.mask = mask_rng.binomial(n=1, p=self.prob_keep, size=inp.shape)
        self.out = self.flag_on * T.cast(self.mask, theano.config.floatX) * inp + self.flag_off * self.prob_keep * inp
        DropoutLayer.layers.append(self)

    @staticmethod
    def setDropoutOn():
        for i in range(0, len(DropoutLayer.layers)):
            DropoutLayer.layers[i].flag_on.set_value(1.0)

    @staticmethod
    def setDropoutOff():
        for i in range(0, len(DropoutLayer.layers)):
            DropoutLayer.layers[i].flag_on.set_value(0.0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: getting weights from a keras network is easy (`model.get_weights()`) but using them in your theano network depends on the implementation, perhaps if you provide it you can get more better answers.

Comment: @S.Mohsensh I added some code snippets to clarify the problem.

Comment: For a specific task like this I would advise you to look at their github and look at how they are doing it: https://github.com/fchollet/keras. Maybe even open an issue there.